# Unable to assign O365 license using MS graph because of service plan dependency

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the MS Graph SDK to assign licenses to my O365 users. It seems something has changed over the week-end as the same request used to work fine last week. So I'm assigning an ENTERPRISEPREMIUM_NOPSTNCONF SKU to a user not having any license yet. I'm disabling all service plans that apply to User, have provisioningStatus = Success and are not one of the services I'm looking for (those being MCOSTANDARD, MCOEV and TEAMS1).

The full request as it goes over the wire looks like this

```
{
"addLicenses": [
    {
        "disabledPlans": [
            "0898bdbb-73b0-471a-81e5-20f1fe4dd66e",
            "4a51bca5-1eff-43f5-878c-177680f191af",
            "efb0351d-3b08-4503-993d-383af8de41e3",
            "5136a095-5cf0-4aff-bec3-e84448b38ea5",
            "33c4f319-9bdd-48d6-9c4d-410b750a4a5a",
            "b1188c4c-1b36-4018-b48b-ee07604f6feb",
            "3fb82609-8c27-4f7b-bd51-30634711ee67",
            "e212cbc7-0961-4c40-9825-01117710dcb1",
            "6c6042f5-6f01-4d67-b8c1-eb99d36eed3e",
            "8e0c0a52-6a6c-4d40-8370-dd62790dcd70",
            "8c7d2df8-86f0-4902-b2ed-a0458298f3b3",
            "07699545-9485-468e-95b6-2fca3738be01",
            "9c0dab89-a30c-4117-86e7-97bda240acd2",
            "8c098270-9dd4-4350-9b30-ba4703f3b36b",
            "4de31727-a228-4ec3-a5bf-8e45b5ca48cc",
            "9f431833-0334-42de-a7dc-70aa40db46db",
            "34c0d7a0-a70f-4668-9238-47f9fc208882",
            "a23b959c-7ce8-4e57-9140-b90eb88a9e97",
            "70d33638-9c74-4d01-bfd3-562de28bd4ba",
            "b737dad2-2f6c-4c65-90e3-ca563267e8b9",
            "bea4c11e-220a-4e6d-8eb8-8ea15d019f90",
            "7547a3fe-08ee-4ccb-b430-5077c5041653",
            "43de0ff5-c92c-492b-9116-175376d08c38",
            "efb87545-963c-4e0d-99df-69c6916d9eb0",
            "5dbe027f-2339-4123-9542-606e4d348a72",
            "e95bec33-7c88-4a70-8e19-b10bd9d0c014"
        ],
        "skuId": "26d45bd9-adf1-46cd-a9e1-51e9a5524128"
    }
],
"removeLicenses": []
}
```

However, my request is no longer to the liking of MS graph. It now throws me a curveball, telling me

```
License assignment failed because service plan 617b097b-4b93-4ede-83de-5f075bb5fb2f depends on the service plan(s) efb87545-963c-4e0d-99df-69c6916d9eb0"
```

So I visted the trusted ole site that ([lists service plan Ids for licensing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-service-plan-reference), and sure enough I found the service plan efb87545-963c-4e0d-99df-69c6916d9eb0, but there's no 617b097b-4b93-4ede-83de-5f075bb5fb2f.

Answer (score 1):

When I assign the license through the O365 portal, it works fine. Looking at what gets returned to me when I then extract that user using MS graph, I see it contains the same license Sku, the same disabled plans, but two additional ones: c4801e8a-cb58-4c35-aca6-f2dcc106f287 and 617b097b-4b93-4ede-83de-5f075bb5fb2f. Neither of which I can find on the licensing page. So it seem the page is in for an update.

But, I can find them when I look at my service plans of the subscribedSkus of my tenant. So it seems we're dealing with INFORMATION_BARRIERS and PREMIUM_ENCRYPTION, two services that have status Disabled. Yet it seems you have to set them as disabled anyway for it to work. Having changed my code to include disabled services in my disable list, I managed to get things working again in my MS graph code. But I couldn't find a change not on this behavior in the MS graph changelog. I guess the license as a whole could've changed and I might not have hit that same scenario before.